# Vagrant box fails to boot properly

Tags: windows-8, virtualbox, virtualization, vagrant

I've been trying to get a vagrant box up and running off of my Windows 8 computer using VirtualBox. `vagrant up` fails when it gets to connecting via ssh however. When I attempt to boot into GUI mode, I am presented with a blank black screen so I assume it's not an SSH problem per-say but an issue with the fact that the box won't even boot all the way in VirtualBox. *Sadly, the same box works fine on another Windows 8 machine.*

I have tried the following versions of VirtualBox:

- 4.2.10
- 4.2.12
- 4.2.14

I have tried the following base boxes (`config.vm.box = 'blah'`):

- base
- precise32
- precise64

Each one presents with the same issues. It'll get past the splash screen, sometimes show a recovery screen, and then go to a black screen with no HDD or Network activity shown in the status bar.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Increase the logging and see what error messages you get. http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/debugging.html

Comment: @spuder Thanks for your thought! I've done that, sadly the only additional info I get is that it is repeatedly trying to SSH in to the box and failing with timeouts/connection refused depending on the length of the timeout I add to the config.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but on a Mac. I tried
`sudo vagrant up` and it worked.
I then moved to another directory where I had the rights without sudo and it worked as well. Again, on a Mac not on Windows but check your permissions.